# How to send an object from activity to fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I just want to use getActivity().data in my fragment to pull in the data object.
It's not working though. Eclipse says that data cannot be resolved.

It looks like there is plenty of information about how to use Bundle to do this.

However, I am wondering how to use getActivity in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Although using `Bundle` is the preferred way and following way must be avoided but just to answer your question, try making the `data` variable static and access it by typecasting the activity `((YourActivity)getActivity()).data`.